# Laravel Foreign Key can not be null

Tags: laravel

My problem is that, In table B has A_id. 
A_id is foreign key, How can I set it is null when I have no id and update it later. 
I've tried with Mutator but It do not work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `->nullable()` to field `A_id` in your migration.

Comment: Try it out, and if it doesn't work I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Great, I knew I had the same problem and solved it rather simply. Hf coding.